# How to extract the text 2 from the html using Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Using Java with Selenium and Eclipse and Chrome.  I was on the page in Chrome I wanted to find an xpath for, so I did an inspect, and then right-click->copy->xpath and it returned the following:

```
 //*[@id="queueForm"]/div[1]/span[3]/text()[2]
```

So I did a

```
 // driver is an instance of ChromeDriver
 String xp = "//*[@id="queueForm"]/div[1]/span[3]/text()[2]";
 WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xp));
```

and I received an error message that that returned an object and not WebElement.  Anyone run into this situation before?  The HTML is like

```
<span class="displayOption" style="float:right;">
        Page <input id="gotoresultpage" type="text" onkeypress="javascript:fncCaptureEnter(this);" size="1" maxlength="4" tabindex="1" value="1" class="navigationMenu" style="width:20px;text-align:right"> of 2
        <input type="button" tabindex="1" value="Go" id="pageGo" name="pageGo" class="navigationButton" onclick="g_objQueueUiController.fncGo();">

        <span class="recordNavigationBack"></span>

        <span class="recordNavigationForwardEnabled" id="pageNext" name="pageNext" onclick="g_objQueueUiController.fncGoToPage('2')"></span>

</span>
```

You can see text "Page" in there and a bit later "of 2".  The page number is in the input box.

So I am trying to get the "of 2" text.  I already got the page number from the value of the input box, but not sure how to get the "of 2".

Comment: Update the question with a bit more of the outerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this `text()` from the end of your XPath expression, the value returned from the [WebDriver.find()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) function must be a [Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node), not the text.

So you need to amend your code to something like:

```
//input[@id='gotoresultpage']
```

example code:

```
WebElement someElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='gotoresultpage']"))
String text = someElement.getText();
```

More information:

- [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: I will try that.  I guess I didn't realize an //input could also have text and not just a value.  I wonder why the copy xpath did not offer that?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
xpath = //span[@class='displayOption']//input[@id='gotoresultpage']

driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath))).getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I need the total number of pages though.  I was able to figure out the current page number.  The value attribute, I believe, would return "1" which is the current page number (1 of 2). Maybe you mean getText() will that work? I think that is what Dimitri said too?

Comment: Endeavour to always add some explanation to your answers. This answer is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

While running Selenium Web-driver, sometimes the page takes a bit more time to load DOM at the back-end and page itself which causes the web-driver to fail a test step. Try using 'Waits' in your code so that it provides a bit more time to load your page and DOM.
Try using this code for wait:

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("")));

Or simply use thread.sleep:
Thread.sleep(Long Millis, Int nanos);

(Example: Thread.sleep(5000, 50000);this will implement 5 seconds sleep between your test steps)

Also, pls note that auto generated xpaths are dynamic which may update on your next test script execution so be vigilant while selecting a web element to be found through web-driver.

Comment: I didn't realize sleep took a second parameter, nanos.  That is 1/1,000,000,000 of a second.  Wow.

Answer (score 0):

The text **of 2** is a *text node*, so to extract the text you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `cssSelector`:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;', new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("#queueForm>div span.displayOption[style*='right']")))).toString());
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript('return arguments[0].childNodes[3].textContent;', new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id="queueForm"]/div//span[@class='displayOption' and contains(@style, 'right')]")))).toString());
  ```

Comment: I still have to learn how to do css selection better. I can try the xpath method.  It is complicated ;-)

Comment: @Tony I will be there to explain you each and every single alphabet of this code.

Answer (score 0):

I did the test in following link : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_form

Here is the HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php" id="form1">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>The "Last name" field below is outside the form element, but still part of the form.</p>

Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" form="form1">

</body>
</html>
```

I got the text "First name" of form

Here my code

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");
driver.findElement(By.id("form1")).getText();
```

Last line return "First name"